# Where can I store my stuff?

Tags: neverwinter-nights-2

I've been having a grand old time running through dungeons, burning zombies into their constituent atoms, and basically looting everything that's not nailed down.  All was fine and dandy until Khelgar started complaining that he didn't like having to carry around all my extra junk.  I told him to pipe down and stop complaining, but he still moves slower than an arthritic camel on a good day.

I tried storing some stuff in the workbenches in the Sunken Flagon, but when I went back, it was all gone!  And there's no chest or anything in my room, so I'm unsure where I can put all my extra stuff that is not useful enough to use or carry with me, but not useless enough for me to offload to a vendor.

Bonus points if there's a way to retrieve the stuff I stuck into the workbenches.  There were some good receipe books in there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no place good to store things, I'm afraid. You might be able to get back the stuff you stashed if you revisit the Flagon later on. If I remember correctly, the various attacks at the Flagon cause the tile set to change, and sometimes the old chests with your stuff in them will get replaced; I wouldn't count on it though.

That said, by this point in the game, you should be able to buy/find Magic Bags that reduce the weight of their contents, and eventually, you'll get your hands on a Bag of Holding, which obviates the need to worry about this stuff. Beyond that, you can always just load up the inventory of the party members who aren't traveling with you. Who cares if Elanee can't run if she's not leaving Crossroads Keep?